# Run class if there is data from requests with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an invoice creation project; that is, if the input city from the form is written, I want the relevant class to be called.
There are mandatory fields for the invoice. If I try to do this with if else, 1000 if elseifs will occur and this will cause the project to become unwieldy.
By the way, I'm using Laravel 8.

What I want to do is: I'm sending this manually right now. but I'm the example you see;
"$invoice->DocumentCurrencyCode = "TRY";" THIS IS IF IT IS ANYTHING OTHER THAN TRY, THERE IS THE CONDITION THAT I HAVE RECEIVED IN THE COMMENT LINE FOR THE INVOICE.

IF OTHER SUBJECT "\Contact();" in class
Telefax from the user may be empty for him
"invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact " Telefax is not created.
What I want to do is create a class according to the data coming from the $data data in 1 Class and the data should be processed there.

```
$invoice = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Invoice();
    $invoice->UBLVersionID = "2.1"; //uluslararası fatura standardı 2.1
    $invoice->CustomizationID = "TR1.2"; //fakat GİB UBLTR olarak isimlendirdiği Türkiye'ye özgü 1.2 efatura formatını kullanıyor.
    $invoice->ProfileID = "TICARIFATURA"; //ticari ve temel olarak iki çeşittir. ticari faturalarda sistem yanıtı(application response) döner.
    $invoice->ID = "FIT2017000000021"; //Eğer fatura ID FIT tarafından oluşacak ise, ID alanı boş, CUST_INV_ID alanı dolu gelmelidir. Eğer kullanıcı firma tarafından oluşacak ise, ID alanı dolu CUST_INV_ID alanı boş olarak gönderilmeli.
    $invoice->CopyIndicator = "false"; //kopyası mı, asıl süret mi olduğu belirlenir
    $invoice->UUID = $uuid; //fatura UUID
    $invoice->IssueDate = "2022-03-05"; //Y-m-d fatura tarihi
    $invoice->IssueTime = date('H:i:s'); //Y-m-d fatura tarihi
    $invoice->InvoiceTypeCode = "SATIS"; //gönderilecek fatura çeşidi, satış, iade vs.
    $invoice->Note = ["Test not", "Test not2"]; //isteğe bağlı not alanı
    $invoice->DocumentCurrencyCode = "TRY"; //efatura para birimi
    #$invoice->TaxCurrencyCode = "EUR"; //efatura para birimi
    #$invoice->PricingCurrencyCode = "EUR"; //efatura para birimi
    #$invoice->PaymentCurrencyCode = "EUR"; //efatura para birimi
    #$invoice->PaymentAlternativeCurrencyCode = "EUR"; //efatura para birimi
    $invoice->LineCountNumeric = 1;  //fatura kalemlerinin sayısı

//Fatura ID otomatik oluşacak ise bu alanı göndermelisiniz.
    $invoice_Document_Refence = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\DocumentReference();
    $invoice_Document_Refence->ID = \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\XMLHelper::CreateGUID();
    $invoice_Document_Refence->IssueDate = ("2022-03-05");
    $invoice_Document_Refence->DocumentTypeCode = "CUST_INV_ID";
    $invoice_Document_Refence->DocumentType = "Xslt";
    $invoice_Document_Refence->Attachment = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Attachment();
    $invoice_Document_Refence->Attachment->EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject = [
        'val' => 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZG',
        'attrs' => [
            'mimeCode="application/xml"',
            'encodingCode="Base64"',
            'characterSetCode="UTF-8"',
            'filename="4C8C8C6D-B7C3-4FAD-AB0B-BCD7D1A59A26.xslt"',
        ]
    ];
    $docRefences[] = $invoice_Document_Refence;


    $invoice->AdditionalDocumentReference = $docRefences;

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\AccountingSupplierParty();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Party();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->WebsiteURI = "http://unlembilisim.com";

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Identifi = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyIdentification();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Identifi->ID = ['val' => '12345678901', 'attrs' => ['schemeID="VKN"']];
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PartyIdentification = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Identifi;


    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Name = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyName();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Name->Name = "Orhan Gazi Başlı";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PartyName = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Name;

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Person = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Person();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Person->FirstName = "Orhan Gazi";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Person->FamilyName = "Başlı";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->Person = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Person;


    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PostalAddress();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->Room = "kapi no";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->StreetName = "cadde";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->BuildingName = "bina";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->BuildingNumber = "bina no";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->CitySubdivisionName = "mahalle";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->CityName = "şehir";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->PostalZone = "posta kodu";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->Region = "asd";

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Country();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country->Name = "Türkiye";

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd->Country = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country;
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PostalAddress = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_PostalAdd;

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyTaxScheme();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxScheme();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema->Name = "erciyes";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema->TaxScheme = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema;
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PartyTaxScheme = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_TaxSchema;

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Contact();
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact->Telephone = "telef";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact->Telefax = "Telefax";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact->ElectronicMail = "ElectronicMail";
    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->Contact = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact;

    $invoice_AccountSupplierParty->Party = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party;

    $invoice->AccountingSupplierParty = $invoice_AccountSupplierParty;


//Customer

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\AccountingCustomerParty();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Party();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->WebsiteURI = "http://unlembilisim.com";

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Identifi = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyIdentification();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Identifi->ID = ['val' => "12345678901", 'attrs' => ['schemeID="VKN"']];
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->PartyIdentification = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Identifi;

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Name = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyName();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Name->Name = "GIB";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->PartyName = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Name;

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PostalAddress();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->Room = "kapi no";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->StreetName = "cadde";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->BuildingName = "bina";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->BuildingNumber = "bina no";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->CitySubdivisionName = "mahalle";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->CityName = "şehir";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->PostalZone = "posta kodu";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->Region = "asd";

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Country();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country->Name = "Türkiye";

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd->Country = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd_Country;
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->PostalAddress = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_PostalAdd;

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyTaxScheme();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxScheme();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema->Name = "erciyes";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema->TaxScheme = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema_Schema;
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->PartyTaxScheme = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_TaxSchema;

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Contact = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Contact();
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Contact->Telephone = "telef";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Contact->Telefax = "Telefax";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Contact->ElectronicMail = "ElectronicMail";
    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party->Contact = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party_Contact;

    $invoice_AccountCustomerParty->Party = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty_Party;

    $invoice->AccountingCustomerParty = $invoice_AccountCustomerParty;

    $invoice_Allowence = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\AllowanceCharge();
    $invoice_Allowence->ChargeIndicator = "false";
    $invoice_Allowence->Amount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice->AllowanceCharge = $invoice_Allowence;

    $invoice_TaxTotal = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxTotal();
    $invoice_TaxTotal->TaxAmount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];

    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxSubtotal();
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal->TaxableAmount = ["val" => "0.99", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal->TaxAmount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];

    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxCategory();
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxScheme();
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema->Name = "KDV";
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema->TaxTypeCode = "0015";

    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category->TaxScheme = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category_Schema;
    $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal->TaxCategory = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal_Category;
    $invoice_TaxTotal->TaxSubtotal = $invoice_TaxTotal_SubTotal;

    $invoice->TaxTotal = $invoice_TaxTotal;

    $invoice_LegalMonetary = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\LegalMonetaryTotal();
    $invoice_LegalMonetary->LineExtensionAmount = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_LegalMonetary->TaxExclusiveAmount = ["val" => "0.99", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_LegalMonetary->TaxInclusiveAmount = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_LegalMonetary->AllowanceTotalAmount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_LegalMonetary->PayableAmount = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];

    $invoice->LegalMonetaryTotal = $invoice_LegalMonetary;

    $invoice_line = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\InvoiceLine();
    $invoice_line->ID = "1";
    $invoice_line->InvoicedQuantity = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['unitCode="CMT"']];
    $invoice_line->LineExtensionAmount = ["val" => "0.99", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];

    $invoice_line_allowence = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\AllowanceCharge();
    $invoice_line_allowence->ChargeIndicator = "false";
    $invoice_line_allowence->MultiplierFactorNumeric = "0.01";
    $invoice_line_allowence->Amount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_line_allowence->BaseAmount = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_line->AllowanceCharge = $invoice_line_allowence;

    $invoice_line_taxtotal = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxTotal();
    $invoice_line_taxtotal->TaxAmount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];;

    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxSubtotal();
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub->TaxableAmount = ["val" => "0.99", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub->TaxAmount = ["val" => "0.01", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub->Percent = "18";

    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxCategory();
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category_schema = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\TaxScheme();
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category_schema->Name = "KDV";
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category_schema->TaxTypeCode = "0015";

    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category->TaxScheme = $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category_schema;
    $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub->TaxCategory = $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub_category;

    $invoice_line_taxtotal->TaxSubtotal = $invoice_line_taxtotal_sub;
    $invoice_line->TaxTotal = $invoice_line_taxtotal;


    $invoice_line_item = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Item();
    $invoice_line_item->Name = "Test Ürün";
    $invoice_line->Item = $invoice_line_item;

    $invoice_line_price = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\Price();
    $invoice_line_price->PriceAmount = ["val" => "1", 'attrs' => ['currencyID="TRY"']];
    $invoice_line->Price = $invoice_line_price;

    $invoice->InvoiceLine = [$invoice_line];

    $xmlHelper = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\XMLHelper($invoice);
    $xml = $xmlHelper->getInvoiceResponseXML();
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by `If I try to do this with if else`? I see no conditionals in the code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want to do is: I'm sending this manually right now. but I'm the example you see;
"$invoice->DocumentCurrencyCode = "TRY";" THIS IS IF IT IS ANYTHING OTHER THAN TRY, THERE IS THE CONDITION THAT I HAVE RECEIVED IN THE COMMENT LINE FOR THE INVOICE.

IF OTHER SUBJECT "\Contact();" in class
Telefax from the user may be empty for him
"invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party_Contact " Telefax is not created.
What I want to do is create a class according to the data coming from the $data data in 1 Class and the data should be processed there.